# Test React Form Submission With Jest & TestUtils

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs, jestjs, reactjs-testutils

I'm having trouble testing a form `submit` event using React, TestUtils and Jest.

I have a component that renders a `<form>` DOM element; the same component also has a method that handles the `onSubmit` event and logs a statement. My goal is to mock the `onSubmit` handler and assert that it is called.

**form-component.cjsx**

```cjsx
module.exports = React.createClass

  # Handle form submissions
  handleSubmit: (e) ->
    console.log 'Make async call'

  # Render a form
  render: ->
    <form onSubmit={@handleSubmit}>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

**__tests__/test-form-component.coffee**

```coffee
jest
  .dontMock '../form-component'

React = require 'react/addons'
TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils
FormComponent = require '../form-component'

describe 'FormComponent', ->
  it 'creates a log statement upon form submission', ->
    # Render a FormComponent into the dom
    formInstance = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<FormComponent />)

    # Mock the `handleSubmit` method
    formInstance.handleSubmit = jest.genMockFunction()

    # Simulate a `submit` event on the form
    TestUtils.Simulate.submit(formInstance)
    # TestUtils.Simulate.submit(formInstance.getDOMNode()) ???

    # I would have expected the mocked function to have been called
    # What gives?!
    expect(formInstance.handleSubmit).toBeCalled()
```

Related Questions:

- [Test a React Component function with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25533036/test-a-react-component-function-with-jest)
- [Test a form with Jest and React JS TestUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470679/test-a-form-with-jest-and-react-js-testutils)

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be your issue exactly?

`React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.submit()` works for me.

If it can help, I was in similar situation and I testing the submit handler this way (using `sinon.js`, `mocha` and `chai`):

```
var renderDocumentJQuery = $(renderDocument.getDOMNode())
this.xhr = sinon.useFakeXMLHttpRequest();
var requests = this.requests = [];
this.xhr.onCreate = function (xhr) {
    requests.push(xhr);
};
renderDocumentJQuery.find('input#person_email').val('test@email.com');
React.addons.TestUtils.Simulate.submit(renderDocumentJQuery.find('form')[0]);
var requestFired = requests[0];
this.xhr.restore();
it('should fire an AJAX with the right params', function(){
  assert.equal(requestFired.requestBody,'campaign_id=123&owner_id=456&person%5Bemail%5D=test%40email.com')
});
it('should fire an AJAX with a POST method', function(){
  assert.equal(requestFired.method,'POST')
});
it('should fire an AJAX with the correct url', function(){
  assert.equal(requestFired.url,'url-for-testing')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an [issue with the way React calls event handlers](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/207) that causes the original handler function to continue to be called even if you attempt to mock it first.

This can apparently be avoided by switching to the [ES6 class syntax](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html) to create component classes, but another simple workaround is to have the event handler just call a second function and mock that. For example:

```
onSubmit: function() {
    this.handleSubmit();  // extra fn needed for Jest
},
handleSubmit: function(){
    this.setState({
        submitted: true
    });
}
```

You would set the form's `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}` and mock `handleSubmit` instead of `onSubmit`. Since this introduces a seemingly unnecessary extra function, if you decide to do this it's probably worth adding a comment to anticipate later attempts to "fix it" which would break the test.